# Which Eclipse plugin enables using XML to define GUI

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, user-interface

I look for answer to that question for long time. I downloaded SWT and it is not it. How to enable XML defined GUI in Java projects in Eclipse? It is so common(many people do that) thing but a the same time I can't find place whre is said how to enable this feature.

I would like to use that in my applications: https://code.google.com/p/atdl4j/

Comment: What makes you think it's common? Who are the many people you refer to? Would they know?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are asking for a way to define your Java GUI layout in an XML file.  In the past I have used [CookSwing](http://cookxml.yuanheng.org/cookswing/) to do this.

You should also take a look at these related questions:

- [java swing library with layout defined in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4468710/274350)
- [suggestions for declarative GUI programming in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/761237/274350)
- [Free XML based java gui language with builder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1782978/274350)

Comment: But then I want tu use their technology and create xmls like this one: http://atdl4j.googlecode.com/svn/atdl4j-ui/trunk/atdl4j-ui-swt/src/test/resources/ABC_strategies.xml and achieve GUI like this one: https://code.google.com/p/atdl4j/wiki/UISWT